# How to put comment in side a VB.NET code block

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is my code block

```
   XY = xyList.[Select](Function(o) New XY() With {.y = New y() With {.xId = o.x.Id _
            , .xName = o.x.xName} _
            , .Stopped = o.Stopped _
            , .PNumber = o.PNumber _
            , .yId = o.yId _
            , .yName = o.yName _
         'need to add some comment here '
            , .Allocated = o.Allocated _
            , .TotalNo = o.TotalNo _
            }).ToList()
```

But wnen I tried with `'` its having compilation issues.

I need to put some comments in between the propeties hwew

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to place a comment INSIDE a multi-line of code?  If so, you can't

Comment: Thanks for fixing the readability, but my answer remains the same - you can't.  See my answer (currently 4th in the list) below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't

Longer answer: It is not valid VB.NET code to have a comment in a multiple-line code block as you're wanting.

If it was C / C++ / C# (or a variant on) then you could use the `/*...*/` style comments - but these are not available in VB.NET

(**Minor update** to remove the phrase "at the start of the line"... as it implies that you can have it at the end of the line.  Again, you can't)

Answer (score -1):

you ca use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C to comment selected lines and use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U to uncomment

OR ' use for each line ...

Answer (score -1):

> '

is not an issue.

you can't give multiple lines comment in VB.Net

Comment: `Now your question is complete and you can't comment multiple lines in VB.Net`